# Why can't I force SSL for Sql Server Reporting Services?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, ssl, reporting-services, socketexception

I am trying to setup SSRS 2008 on Windows Server 2008. It seems to work as expected when I access the web interface through HTTP, but when using HTTPS the following error is what I get: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

From a look at the log files, it is revealed that the inner exception is "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". This makes me think, that the error occurs during a service call from the Report Manager to the web service.

I have configured both the web service and the Report Manager with an SSL-binding on a non-default port (8091), using a certificate signed using my own CA certificate. The server certificate is installed in (and used by) IIS7, and the CA certificate is added to "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" on the "Local Computer" certificate store.

Searching the net for the specific error message(s) gives me a lot of information on how to deal with the problem, if the client application is my own .NET application. The most prevalent solution seems to be about setting the property "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol" to "SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3", but I guess that is not possible for me to do when the client is a precompiled web application (Report Manager).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Requests now fail with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." The stack trace in the log file tells me that the exception occurs at SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse, which I would expect to be "later" in the SOAP-processing than the error I had before.

Any new ideas?

Comment: I second this question, having similar issues... Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to this problem has been found here: http://prologika.com/CS/forums/t/946.aspx

In rsreportserver.config I have replaced this section:

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
  <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
  <RSWindowsNTLM/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

with this:

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
  <RSWindowsBasic/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
```

and everything now works.